# Rails 5: How to get controller data in the AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have referred so many articles on the topic, after which I have ended up more confused than understanding anything clearly. It mainly because of the many ways the same thing is done in rails.

Old school method of making ajax calls:
 1. Javascript watches for some event.
 2. When that event occurs (for example: button click) , you catch that in javascript, make an ajax call, handle the success or error response within that ajax call.

Trying to do this with rails 5, the rails way:
1. Having problem in getting the data from controller to javascript.

controller:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end

  def foo
    @result = 'Hello World'
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {@result}
    end
  end
end
```

In my view I have a form which has remote: true, and is responsible for submitting the AJAX request to the foo action in the controller. Something like:

```
=form_tag url_for(action: 'foo'), remote: true, id: 'element-form' do
  =some input ....
  =some input ...
```

Javascript: foo.js.erb in /views/some/foo.js.erb

```
$('#element-form').on ('ajax:complete', doSomething)

function doSomething(event, data) {
  console.log(data) // prints undefined
}

$('#element-form').on ('ajax:error', doSomethingElse)

function doSomethingElse(event, data) {
  console.log(data) // prints undefined
}
```

1. What is it that I am doing wrong, because of which I can't seem to access the data from controller in the ajax onsuccess function?
2. I feel very icky about using the *.js.erb file. I kind of feel like I am mixing up everything (views and javascript).
3. If I don't want to use *.js.erb for my javascript, but I still want to do AJAX calls the rails way (using the remote: true, respond_to...), is there a way I can pass my controllers data to my javascript files where I will be handling the AJAX response.
4. How can I define the success and error handlers for ajax response separately? Is there some rails convention that I am missing, which provides this automagically?

When I inspect the ajax call in the browser, I can see that I am getting a valid response that includes the entire javascript that is defined in the foo.js.erb file.

My biggest problem is not any particular piece of code, but understanding how all of the pieces fit together. To summarize, I just can't seem to get the data-flow or the request response cycle that take place when making an ajax request in a rails 5 environment. Links to any references on this topic is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally was able to get the whole ajax request response cycle to work. Here's how I set up the whole thing.

The controller logic remains the same.
In-order to get finer control over the ajax request, I included the logic in the `some_controller.js` file. As Sergio pointed out in one of his comments, in his answer, I think its too late to add any callback methods in the *.js.erb file.

So the javascript code looks like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#some_element').on('some_event', function doSomething() {
    makeAjaxCall();
  });

  function makeAjaxCall() {
    Rails.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {mock_data: mock_data},
        url: 'post_url',
        success: function(response){...},
        error: function(error){...}
      });
  }
});
```

Now the important part is what happens when your post method in rails controller (action) completes. I believe rails is looking for some view to render. In this case it looks for a js view which should have the same name as the action method (action_method.js.erb)

So any controller data that you want to send to the ajax callback blocks, can be simply put in this js view. So in my case the Javascript: foo.js.erb in /views/some/foo.js.erb changed to:

```
<%=@result %>
```

After all this, the control comes back to the client side javascript, which in our case is the ajax success callback method and whatever you put in the `*.js.erb` file becomes available to you in the response.

Answer (score -1):

`foo.js.erb` is an ERB view, like any other. So you reference your controller data as usual.

```
 console.log("<%= @result %>");
```

(you don't need to setup that `ajax:complete` in the .js.erb, btw)

Comment: Thanks. I see that the embedded ruby code helps in accessing controller data. But say, I want to handle the `success` and `error` response from ajax separately, how can I handle it without setting up the `ajax: complete` and `ajax:error`?

Isn't that how it used to be done?

`$.ajax({method: method,
url: action,
data: data,
success: function(result){
//do something...;
},
error: function(result){
//do something else...;
}});`

Comment: I edited my post and expanded the question a bit more to include the part of handling ajax success and error responses.

Comment: @ChillBan123 If you need the fine controls, then it's better to use "raw" `$.ajax` call. Remote forms greatly simplify the "happy path" of sending forms asynchronously, that's what they should be used for.

Comment: @ChillBan123 You can still set up success/error handlers for your form, but it's __too late__ to do it in your .js.erb view. The response is already a success. You need to have it set up _before_ user clicks submit (on page load, maybe?)

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. Probably the key is in understanding clearly, the order in which various components (the html, javascript, erb views) get rendered.
If I am understanding correctly, then I would have to handle all of this in a regular `*.js` file, using raw `$.ajax` call, to get finer control over the ajax request.
I will test this theory and post back a.s.a.p
Thanks again for discussing :)

Comment: @ChillBan123: so, how did it go?

Comment: Although I did the changes, I haven't been able to test that yet. I will be posting back in a few hours.

Comment: I posted the working solution as an answer. Although I got it to work the way I want, I wonder if there is a better way? I am pretty sure I have seen blog posts where people have included the ajax callbacks in the `*.js.erb` files. Don't know if I read it wrong or if I missed something in getting that approach to work.
Thanks for pointing out some of the subtle things. I will post back if at all I can get the ajax stuff to work in the `*.js.erb` files.